# WinAPI GetSystemMenu without WS_SYSMENU in style

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

As title said, How can I get system menu (via `GetSystemMenu`) but in window style missed `WS_SYSMENU`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If window at first was with WS_SYSMENU, but then WS_SYSMENU was deleted, - you can, if window was created without WS_SYSMENU - you can't.

Comment: Window was created with `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` style and in `WM_CREATE` message I call: `SetWindowLong(_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW &~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZE | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_SYSMENU));` then `SetWindowPos(_hWnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);`. Is it possible?

Comment: delete WS_SYSMENU on WM_CREATE = create without WS_SYSMENU

Comment: I change above code right after `CreateWindowEx` call but in `WM_CONTEXMENU` API `GetSystemMenu` still return NULL, Where can I put the above code?

Comment: don't sure what you want really, but you can call GetSystemMenu on WM_CREATE before deleting WS_SYSMENU (then retval!=0), and then it'll be possible to call TrackPopupMenu on WM_CONTEXTMENU

Comment: Btw, to make this popupmenu workable: on (WM_COMMAND && lParam==0) call something like PostMessage(WM_SYSCOMMAND,wParam,0).